# Scoket.IO v1.0.x Token based auth -- can't pass token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I am using [this tutorial](http://wlkns.co/node-js/socket-io-authentication-tutorial-server-and-client/) to get the basics of a token-based auth system in place. Here is the code I'm using:

In app.html:

```
var socket = io('', {
  // originally I thought the $.param might've been a problem, so I hard coded a token instead
  // query: $.param({token: 'i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R'})
  query: "token=i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R"
});
```

In index.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var tokens = [
  'i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R',
  'oWD4sh1eU2Yhn95C05t2YKrKMVWoAFAk'
];

io.set('authorization', function(handshakeData, callback) {

    console.log(handshakeData.query);

    // Some basic validation to make sure a token was passed
    if ( handshakeData.query.token === undefined || handshakeData.query.token.length === 0 ) {
        console.log('No token')
        return false;
    }

    // Loop through the valid tokens, to validate the token passed
    var validated = false;
    for ( var key in tokens ) {
        if ( key == handshakeData.query.token ) {
            validated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If valid, continue to callback the next function
    if ( validated ) {
        console.log('Good token');
        return callback(null, true);
    } else {
        console.log('Bad token');
        return false;
    }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection ' + socket.id);
});
```

But, when I navigate to my server, I'm getting console errors:

```
if ( handshakeData.query.token === undefined || handshakeData.query.token.
                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'token' of undefined
....
```

And the `console.log(handshakeData.query);` returns `undefined`.

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Which version of socket.io are using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For v1.0.x**

After some tinkering and reading through the tangled web that is socket.io documentation, I came up with the following solution:

app.html:

```
// in version 1.0 the first param is the options object
var socket = io({
    query: $.param({token: 'i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R'})
});
```

Index.js:

```
// io.use instead of io.set
io.use(function(socket, next) {
    var handshakeData = socket.request;

    // "query" lives in _query
    var query = handshakeData._query

    if ( query.token === undefined || query.token.length === 0 ) {
        console.log('No token')
        return false;
    }

    // the for loop was returning the array key and was
    // comparing that to the token val, so I fixed that
    var validated = false;
    for ( var key in tokens ) {
        console.log(tokens[key]);
        if ( tokens[key] == query.token ) {
            validated = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // This now returns next() if true and nothing if false
    if (validated) {
        next();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the new socket.io v 1.0 which is not what the tutorial was written for.

I followed the same tutorial and my code was identical to yours and ran without error.

You can print out the entire handshake data to the console and it should look something like this:

```
    { headers: 
   { host: '_yourip/_yourPort',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
     origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
     accept: '*/*',
     referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' },
  address: { address: '_ipAdress', port: _yourPort },
  time: 'Thu May 29 2014 16:13:51 GMT-0600 (MDT)',
  query: { token: 'i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R', t: '1401401631469' },
  url: '/socket.io/1/?token= i271az2Z0PMjhd6w0rX019g0iS7c2q4R&t=1401401631469',
  xdomain: true,
  secure: undefined,
  issued: 1401401631471 }
```

If the query is not set it will appear there as query:{} (in the previous socket.io)

Edit: It seems you have figured it out. If you wish to follow the tutorial in the version it was written for you can add

```
socket.io : 0.9.*
```

to the dependencies in your package.json, but socket.io's website is overhauled for the new version.

Comment: I assumed the tutorial would work because in the article they state `In this tutorial I am using version 0.9.16, installed from npm, released 7 months ago. It should be compatible with all new versions, including 1.0+.`. Unfortunately I did have to make quite a few changed to get it to work in the 1.x branch. I've updated the OP and my answer to indicate that I was using v1.x.